# Is there a page with all languages currently available on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, languages

I see some people have difficulty in asking questions if they are not native English speakers. I know I can suggest http://pt.stackoverflow.com to Portuguese speakers, http://ru.stackoverflow.com to Russian speakers and http://ja.stackoverflow.com to Japanese speakers; but I wanna know if there's a page with a list of all languages currently available for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Andrew T. Can you, please, post this comment as an answer? Since they all are right, I think yours deserve be the 'right answer' because it's the quickest way and can be accessed from any page at any time;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also search it from the site selector drop down, and type "stackoverflow". The search includes the *site's domain* (`http://*.stackoverflow.com`), so it's language agnostic and can be accessed everywhere.

[image: overflow]

Answer (score 5):

Let's set the record straight:

- Stack Overflow is *one* site.  There are *many* different sites, each with their own meta and their own community.
- The best place to look is the [Stack Exchange site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name), ordered by name.  You'll see all of the Stack Overflow sites grouped together (and Japanese Stack Exchange at the very bottom because in Unicode, ASCII characters < Katakana).

Answer (score 4):

You may do a [search in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack+overflow).

Alternatively, here is a [list in a community wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117167/).